# Why is dockerized Rails app raising "PG::ConnectionBad"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am trying to "dockerize" an existing Rails development app. This is my first time experimenting with Docker.

After searching and reading a lot of information online, I finally managed to get a container up and running with several services: app, postgres, redis, sidekiq and guard.

But I am having trouble connecting to the database.

```
Starting postgres ... done
Starting redis    ... done
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Address not available
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

No doubt there is a simple configuration that I've overlooked, but I've been unable to figure out what or find a suitable guide.

I did notice that the IP addresses appear not to match.

```
$ docker-compose ps
Name                  State   Ports
------------------------------------------------------
postgres              Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
```

The top error suggests postgres should be at 127.0.0.1. Could this be the reason?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

#### Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.4-alpine

# Install runtime dependencies
RUN apk add --update --virtual runtime-deps postgresql-client nodejs libffi-dev readline-dev yarn git

RUN apk add --virtual build-deps build-base postgresql-dev libc-dev linux-headers libxml2-dev libxslt-dev readline-dev git 

# Copy the app's code into the container
ENV APP_HOME /app
COPY . $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# Budnle gems
RUN bundle install --jobs 4

# Install Yarn packages
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn upgrade

# Configure production environment variables
ENV RAILS_ENV=production \
    RACK_ENV=production

# Expose port 3000 from the container
EXPOSE 3000

# Run puma server
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - $HOME/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql
    image: postgres:9.6.9

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    links:
      - postgres
    image: redis:5.0-rc

  web:
    container_name: web
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: /bin/sh -c "rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
  
  guard:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: bundle exec guard --no-bundler-warning --no-interactions

  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env

volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
  sidekiq:
  guard:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker - Rails app cannot connect to linked Postgres container (doesn't seem to be running)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196409/docker-rails-app-cannot-connect-to-linked-postgres-container-doesnt-seem-to)

Comment: From the point of view of your application, the database will be visible at the host name `postgres` (the name of the block in the `docker-compose.yml` file).  You can remove all of the `container_name:` and `links:` sections, they don't really have a practical effect.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, a couple questions: 1) my database.yml contains `host: postgres` but I am still seeing this error. Is there something else I should change. 2) I had thought that `links:` ensures that e.g. the postgres services is available before any attempt is made to start the web service. Have I misunderstood this? Thanks!

Comment: `links` is now considered a legacy/potentially deprecated feature. Since you're using the latest v3 syntax you might want to look at [depends on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)

Comment: ...and `depends_on:` is a fairly weak ordering constraint (if you `docker-compose up web` then `depends_on:` will cause it to start `postgres` too, but "start" doesn't guarantee it'll be done with first-time setup and be listening for connections).

Comment: thanks @DavidMaze, this is really useful for a beginner. is there a better way to ensure dependencies are fully setup before moving on to the next service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the official postgres docker container, the [official documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) has some related information:

```
The PostgreSQL image sets up trust authentication locally so you may 
notice a password is not required when connecting from localhost 
(inside the same container). However, a password will be required 
if connecting from a different host/container.
```

Since you're not inside the same container, it looks like you may need to use a `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`. I tested this with a sample app locally, using your `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` and I needed to:

- Add `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` to both the `web` and `postgres` sections in the respective `env`/`environment` (you'll add these to the `.env` file you're including)
- Add `username` and `password` keys to the `database.yml` in the relevant sections to pull in the environment variables I set above

`database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: postgres
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_USER"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"] %>
```

With those changes I was able to connect to the postgres container/database from the web container.

My `docker-compose ps` shows similar to yours:

```
   Name                      Command                State             Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hello_app_sidekiq_1   bundle exec sidekiq -C con ...   Exit 127
postgres              docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up         0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
redis                 docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up         0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp
web                   /bin/sh -c bundle exec rai ...   Up         0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp
```

I'm able to run `docker-compose run --rm web /bin/ash` and drop into a `rails console`, run `rails db:migrate`, etc. without issue with the changes above.

Comment: thanks @jay, this is very useful and seems to have solved my issue. There still seems to be some weirdness happening, with postgres starting up, shutting down then starting up again (see gist), but this is largely cosmetic and isnt affecting the app. Thanks! https://gist.github.com/ahharvey/f1b2dafa614e53820638df66731da523

Comment: BTW, I'm also having some trouble getting Guard running. Any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54026795/why-is-guard-not-detecting-file-changes-after-dockerizing-rails-app

Comment: @AndyHarvey I think most of those messages are normal, but the database does not, followed by does exist kind of jumps out. You'll need to figure out a strategy for creating that table if it doesn't exist. This will be dependent upon a few things (does your database container persist across up/down for one). That will help you decide whether you want to run the db:create manually or as part of your compose. Regardless, this might be worth a look: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ I've used `wait_for_it.sh` in the past successfully