# Why is Guard not detecting file changes after dockerizing Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, guard

I am trying to "dockerize" an existing Rails development app. This is my first time experimenting with Docker.

I want to set up Guard to listen for file changes and run relevant specs.

The Guard service appears to be running correctly, and the logs show:

```
guard_1     | 16:35:12 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/app'
```

But when I edit/save spec files Guard is not running any tests.

This is an existing app that I'm moving into Docker. It has a guardfile that works outside of Docker.

I've searched and read a number of posts (e.g. [this one](https://www.chrisblunt.com/ruby-on-rails-running-tests-with-guard-and-docker/)), but I'm not sure where to start debugging this. Can anyone point me in the right direction and get Guard listening to file changes.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - $HOME/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql
    image: postgres:9.6.9

  redis:
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    image: redis:5.0-rc

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: /bin/sh -c "rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env

  guard:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: bundle exec guard --no-bundler-warning --no-interactions

  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env

volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
  sidekiq:
  guard:
```

#### Guardfile

```
guard 'spring', bundler: true do
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch(%r{^config/})
  watch(%r{^spec/(support|factories)/})
  watch(%r{^spec/factory.rb})
end

guard :rspec, cmd: "bundle exec rspec" do
  require "guard/rspec/dsl"
  dsl = Guard::RSpec::Dsl.new(self)

  # RSpec files
  rspec = dsl.rspec
  watch(rspec.spec_files)

  # Ruby files
  ruby = dsl.ruby
  dsl.watch_spec_files_for(ruby.lib_files)

  # Rails files
  rails = dsl.rails(view_extensions: %w(erb haml slim))
  dsl.watch_spec_files_for(rails.app_files)
  dsl.watch_spec_files_for(rails.views)

  watch(rails.controllers) do |m|
    [
      rspec.spec.call("routing/#{m[1]}_routing"),
      rspec.spec.call("controllers/#{m[1]}_controller"),
      rspec.spec.call("acceptance/#{m[1]}")
    ]
  end

  # Rails config changes
  watch(rails.spec_helper)     { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rails.routes)          { "#{rspec.spec_dir}/routing" }
  watch(rails.app_controller)  { "#{rspec.spec_dir}/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(rails.view_dirs)     { |m| rspec.spec.call("features/#{m[1]}") }
  watch(rails.layouts)       { |m| rspec.spec.call("features/#{m[1]}") }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$}) do |m|
    Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || "spec/acceptance"
  end
  ignore %r{^spec/support/concerns/}
end

guard 'brakeman', :run_on_start => true do
  watch(%r{^app/.+\.(erb|haml|rhtml|rb)$})
  watch(%r{^config/.+\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
end
```

Comment: Can you post your Guardfile? And try adding `tty: true` underneath your `guard` service? Also, have you tried running your guard command outside of docker to make sure it's configured correctly? I'd try and run it standalone to make sure it's seeing the changes to make sure you've configured it correctly, then move it into a container. Also, are you using minitest, or rspec?

Comment: Thanks @JayDorsey, I will add the guardfile above. I am using Rspec. If I run `bundle exec guard` from the command prompt it runs correctly. I’m away from my dev computer just now, but will try running this from a docker bash prompt and report back. Same with the `tty: true` config. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're making changes on your local filesystem and expected guard, inside the container, to trigger.

If so, the missing link is your `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
guard:
  build: .
  env_file:
    - .env
  command: bundle exec guard --no-bundler-warning --no-interactions
  volumes:
    - .:/app
```

You need to mount the volume of your root (Rails root) directory inside the container so that the changes are reflected. Without this line, your container(s) only sees what was available at build time, and not the changes.

Comment: thanks @Jay, I think this is working. It's taking me a while to confirm this because: 1. Guard is veeerrryy slow to respond from within the Docker container, 2. none of my gems seem to be autoloading when Guard launches (e.g., NameError: uninitialized constant FactoryBot). Any idea why this might be?

Comment: The slowness might be due to how Docker mounts the filesystem in Docker. It's the same on my system (macOS). This is an outstanding known issue. You can look at http://docker-sync.io/. I haven't tested it, but it looks like it exists to combat this issue. Also can look at this: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/ Is the autoloading issue only present in your Guard container? Can you confirm it's not just an old(er) log file that's showing the factorybot error? I seem to recall the logs being persistent and showing errors from previous iterations

Comment: Given this slowness issue, do you (or people) actually use Docker in this way with file monitoring and tests? It is close to being unusable on my machine.

Comment: The gem thing is odd. For example, I fixed the FactoryBot issue by adding `require 'factory_bot'` to spec/support/factory_bot.rb. But then I started seeing the same error for whatever gem is called next. So the gems seem to be available, just not enabled. The app works perfectly in all other environments without needing to `require` gems. Not sure where to begin with this one!

Comment: I don't use it for local Dev because of that issue. I've never tried the docker-sync to but I suspect it might be a viable solution. I have used it to speed up tests and deploys for pipelines that support Docker. The gem issue sounds weird. Did you try passing bundler: true in your Guardfile? I think you were running bundle exec guard, but I think there's another flag.

Comment: The guard flag I was talking about was `, bundler: true`, which you have for some of your guards but not all. That's the only thing I could think might be causing that issue, considering gems are working elsewhere. Assuming your compose file is similiar to the other one and you haven't also changed your bundle path or mountings for where gems get installed

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem and have been wondering about existing solutions that didn't really work. The key solution to your problem (if you are on OSX of course) is to understand the difference between "Docker Toolbox" and "Docker for Mac".

This article gives a lot of insight: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/

TL;DR

If you are on Mac, you need to use Docker for Mac to have the benefits of osxfs. **If you do this you will not need docker-sync!**